# How to add dynamic column with static value in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have structure of table like below:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://vw118287.ds.dev.accenture.com> desc sample2;
Getting log thread is interrupted, since query is done!
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
|  col_name   | data_type  | comment  |
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
| event_text  | string     |          |
| load_date   | string     |          |
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
```

Now, I want to add a new column with constant value while inserting data into this table so I ran below query:

```
insert into table sample2 select event_text,'2019','Sample' as SampleColumn from ccs_service_optimization_9401.so_wireless_radius_summary ;
```

It throws below error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:18 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different 'sample2': Table insclause-0 has 2 columns, but query has 3 columns.
```

I read in of the SO posts that this isn't possible in Hive but I believe there must be some or other way. Anyone has any idea about this ??

Comment: One way is to make your column with constant value being a partition column, then insert into partition your data

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Hive. Table DDL is not dynamic and DML query does not affect table definition.

If you want to add column, perform [alter table DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns) before insert.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columns SampleColumn  string;
```

Also if the table is [external](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables), you can drop and create it with additional column, old data will remain, new column if it is the last one will be null for old data;

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin. I already know this but it still doesn't answer my question. Is it possible or not ?? Is there any way to make this table as dynamic?

Comment: @RushHour You can generate drop/create sentences using some other tools like shell and execute them in Hive for example. But it's not possible to do directly in Hive unfortunately. If you need the solution using some other tool, then your question is too broad. Be more specific and show your attempt, this will help to understand your problem better

Comment: No Thanks, I just wanted to understand whether it is directly possible in hive or not.

Answer (score 0):

From `Hive version > 2.0` it supports to specify columns names in the insert script

```
insert into table sample2 (col_name, data_type, comment ) select event_text,'2019','Sample' as SampleColumn from ccs_service_optimization_9401.so_wireless_radius_summary;
```

If your table is partitioned then the column specification is not supported and you might need to specify the partitioned column during the insert.